# IE8 Background-image at pseudo

Tags: internet-explorer-8

My custom checkbox in IE8 fails to work properly.
I have an element with a pseudo :before, and when the label-element has the class .checked, it must change the properties of the pseudo:before.

The border will change from red to green, but the image won't reposition, it only repositions the second time when clicked. Kinda weird.

HTML:

```
<label for="a" class="default-checkbox">
    <input id="a" data-validate="must-check" name="a" type="checkbox">
    SOMETHING BLA BLA
</label>
```

Sass:

```
                .default-checkbox {
                    width: 55%; height: auto;
                    position: relative;
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 0 20px;
                    margin: 0;
                    line-height: 1.5em;
                    &:before {
                        border: 1px solid red;
                        //content: '\0020';
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        top: -15px;
                        display: inline-block;
                        width: 47px; height: 44px;
                        left: -20px;
                        background-image: url(../images/default-checkbox.png);
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: 0 0;
                    }
                    &.checked {
                        &:before {
                            content: '.'; // used a dot to apply the change
                            border: 1px solid green;
                            background-position: 0 -44px;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the issue, or let me say: I've found a bug in IE8.
If I change the content:'' property in the :before when checked, it works fine. So the content property must be different from the .checked en and unchecked state (class).
It works, but really weird!